# nginx: Is it safe to use $http_host for the server root?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to serve arbitrary domain names with my nginx server.

This bit of configuration seems to work just fine:

```
    location / {
        root   /www/$http_host;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

For example, serving a request for `www.mydomain.com` would look for a file in `/www/www.mydomain.com/`. It works, that looks perfect.

However I'm not sure that would be safe. Would this allow any kind of directory traversal or other security issue? What's the validation done on $http_host by nginx?

Comment: My biggest concern would be `http_host` containing something like `../../etc/passwd`, but I don't think it's possible for it to contain `/`, so it might be safe. Edit: I would test it by passing the `Host` header manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As remarked by **jordanm** non validated may lead to a client escaping from the `/www` directory and accessing any file.

Fortunately host names **are** validated (cf. the [source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/585f08ed0b89a1216360e98d40b68366d489c241/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2065)) and tricks like using two consecutive dots `..` or a path separator `/` won't work: **nginx** will return `400 Bad Header`. The validation might be stricter and allow only [valid DNS labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063213/regular-expression-for-validating-dns-label-host-name), but that is a personal taste.

Nevertheless, with such a configuration, you can not put anything private in the `/www` directory, so I would rather use:

```
root /www/$http_host/html
```

Comment: Awesome, that source code link was exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find. Great suggestion for the `/html` also, thanks!